# RINGER_MODE_SILENT makes the app stopping

Tags: android, silent, vibration

I have a strange problem, I'm working on an app that changes the phone mode to normal, vibrate or silent.

I got normal and vibrate working just fine, but silent is causing app to stop working!

I have no compile error and the codes should be fine.

here are my codes:

```
normalBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
        }
    });

    vibrateBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);
        }
    });

    silentBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
        }
    });
```

I also added the permission in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
```

And FYI, I'm not testing on AVD Manager, I don't know why it takes more than 10 minutes to run, so I send the apk file to my device (Samsung Galaxy Note8 with Android 7.1.1) and test there becuase this way is much faster.

Am I missing something here? Or it is a problem with my phone software?

Thank you

Comment: What about your logcat??? please add this information.

Comment: "but silent is  causing app to stop working!" - then please add the relevant Logcat parts as well as enough code to reproduce the problem

Comment: As I said, Android Emulator is not working on my computer and I have to send the apk file to my phone everytime I want to test it.